# Hackerrank: Plus Minus

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find the fraction of positive, negative, and zero in the array but the function is not returning anything.

```js
var noOfPostive = 0;
var noOfNegative = 0;
var noOfZero = 0;

function plusMinus(arr) {
  /*
   * Write your code here.
   
   */
  var length = arr.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (i > 0) {
      noOfPostive += 1;
    } else if (i < 0) {
      noOfNegative += 1;
    } else {
      noOfZero += 1;
    }

    var FractionOfPostive = noOfPostive / length;
    var FractionOfNegative = noOfNegative / length;
    var FractionOfZero = noOfZero / length;
    return FractionOfPostive, FractionOfPostive, FractionOfZero;

  }
}

plusMinus([-4,3,-9,0,4,1]);
```

Comment: `FractionOfPostive, FractionOfPostive, FractionOfZero` are global, you can access them outside the function. Also, one can't return many variables from a function, either use array or object.

Comment: The onyl value returned is fractionOfZero, since your return statement only returns the last in the list separated by commas, so better to `return { FractionOfPostive, FractionOfPostive, FractionOfZero }`. You also might want to move your `noOf` variables into the function as you only want them to be used once in there and then discarded.

Comment: use arr[i] instead of i, arr[i] will get you the values, where as i will get you index.

Comment: @somethinghere it still not returning anything on hacker rank

Comment: What does parseFloat do Thank you

Answer (score 8):

**This is a simple and fast solution:**

you can use the filter function to iterate in the array and get a new array only with the numbers that fulfill the condition; positive (n> 0), negative (n <0) and neutral (n == 0) numbers. In the same variable you can calculate the size of the returned array and divide it by the size of the original array, so you get the fraction, which you must format to only 6 decimal places with toFixed(6) and print an output in the requested format.

```
function plusMinus(arr) {
    let positive = arr.filter(number => number > 0).length / arr.length;
    let negative = arr.filter(number => number < 0).length / arr.length;;
    let zeronums = arr.filter(number => number == 0).length / arr.length;;
    return console.log(positive.toFixed(6) + '\n' + negative.toFixed(6) + '\n' + zeronums.toFixed(6))
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd use [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to get the result, combined with [Math.sign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sign) which will return 0, 1 or -1 depending on if the number is 0, positive or negative. Below will return an array of arrays, each holding the identifier for +,0,- as the first element, and the fraction as the second one.

```js
function plusMinus(arr) {
  return Object.entries(arr.reduce((a, b) => {
    let sign = Math.sign(b);
    a[sign] = (a[sign] || 0) + 1;
    return a;
  }, {})).map(e => [e[0], e[1] / arr.length]);
}

console.log(plusMinus([-4, 3, -9, 0, 4, 1]));
```

Comment: that's an incredibly intelligent solution !

Answer (score 2):

I did this simple code in Python where first it takes the nos of elements of the array from the user and then the array elements.
After this only comparison is done and the counter is incremented.

Here's the code:

```
pos=0
neg=0
z=0

n = int(input().strip())
arr = [int(arr_temp) for arr_temp in input().strip().split(' ')]


for num in arr:
    if num>0:
        pos+=1

    elif num == 0:
        z+=1
    elif num<0:
        neg+=1

print(pos/n)
print(neg/n)
print(z/n)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function plusMinus(arr) {
    let decimal = 6;
    let length = arr.length;
    let positive = arr.filter(val => val > 0).length;
    let negative = arr.filter(val => val < 0).length;
    let zero = arr.filter(val => val == 0).length;

    function findRatio(num) {
        return console.log(parseFloat(num / length).toPrecision(decimal));
    }
    
    findRatio(positive);
    findRatio(negative);
    findRatio(zero);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of, when you are looping in an array with `for`, you are actually storing the `index` in `i`, so you still need to check the value at that `index` in the `array`:

```
let value = arr[ i ]
```

Secondly, your `return` statement was *inside* your `for` loop, so it didn't even run once before it returned.

Thirdly, your return values need to be a single value or object, so you can't `return a, b, c;`, as only `c` would be returned.

See below for all of the above applied. Also note that I have moved your variables to inside your `function` definition - if you run this function twice it will always reset its values to zero, so it does not keep increasing the amount (your numbers would become bigger than 1 after a single run). I have also used `let` variables inside blocks (like `let i` and `let value` - these don't do anything in particular, but they have to do with scoping and memory. If inside a block, use `let`, but don't worry too much there).

```js
function plusMinus( arr ){
  
  var pos = 0;
  var neg = 0;
  var zero = 0;
  var length = arr.length;

  for( let i = 0; i < length; i++ ){
    
    let value = arr[ i ];
    
    if( value > 0 ){
    
      pos += 1;
      
    } else if( value < 0 ) {
    
      neg += 1;
      
    } else {
    
      zero += 1;
      
    }
   
  }

  var FractionOfPostive = pos / length;
  var FractionOfNegative = neg / length;
  var FractionOfZero = zero / length;
    
  return {
    FractionOfPostive,
    FractionOfNegative,
    FractionOfZero
  };
    
}

console.log( plusMinus([-4,3,-9,0,4,1]) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need do perform couple of fixes in your code. The following typos exist in your code.

***Inaccurate return statement :***

return can not send multiple variable as a result. You need to store your result in an array and send the array back to caller.

***Not ofchecking array value :***

`if(i>0)` doesn't mean anything. If you need to check if the array value is positive or not then you need to do

```
if(arr[i]>0)
```

***Misplaced last curly brace of for loop :***

also you have typo in your for loop. You've extended your for loop to the end of the function.That means your positive or negative count also inside the for loop. That means they will loose the previous computed result during each iteration.

```js
var noOfPostive = 0;
var noOfNegative = 0;
var noOfZero = 0;

function plusMinus(arr) {
  /*
   * Write your code here.
   
   */
  var length = arr.length
  var result = []
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] > 0) {
      noOfPostive += 1;
    } else if (arr[i] < 0) {
      noOfNegative += 1;
    } else {
      noOfZero += 1;
    }

    }
    var FractionOfPostive = parseFloat(noOfPostive / length);
    var FractionOfNegative = parseFloat(noOfNegative / length);
    var FractionOfZero = parseFloat(noOfZero / length);

 result.push(FractionOfPostive,FractionOfNegative,FractionOfZero)
    return result;

  
}

console.log(plusMinus([-4,3,-9,0,4,1]));
```

### **Consider not using a For-Loop:**

Here you have seen that you misplaced the last curly brace of your for loop.Thus you got unexpected result.Loops sometime creates problem.To avoid using for loops you can use [**ES6 Generator functions**](https://davidwalsh.name/es6-generators) for this purpose instead of a for loop.This is  functional approach to solve this problem.

```
function plusMinus(arr) {

    var length = arr.length
    var result = []

    function* generateResult(){
       var positives = arr.filter((index,elem) => elem>0)
       yield positives.length
       var negatives = arr.filter((index,elem) =>elem<0)
       yield negatives.length
       var zeros = arr.filter((index,elem) => elem==0)
       yield zeros.length
    }

    var start = generateResult()

    var FractionOfPostive = parseFloat(start.next().value / length);
    var FractionOfNegative = parseFloat(start.next().value / length);
    var FractionOfZero = parseFloat(start.next().value / length);

    return {FractionOfPostive,FractionOfNegative,FractionOfZero};


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function plusMinus(arr) {

    let positives = 0
    let negatives = 0
    let zeros = 0
    const length=arr.length

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length;i++){
        if (arr[i] > 0) {
            positives++
        } else if (arr[i] < 0) {
            negatives++
        } else {
            zeros ++
        }
    }

    const positiveRatio = Number(positives / length).toFixed(6)
    const negativeRatio = Number(negatives / length).toFixed(6)
    const zeroRatio = Number(zeros / length).toFixed(6)

    console.log(positiveRatio)
    console.log(negativeRatio)
    console.log(zeroRatio)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function plusMinus($arr) {
$countArr = count($arr);
$positive = 0;
$negative = 0;
$zero = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < $countArr; $i++){
    if($arr[$i] > 0){
        $positive += 1;
    }
    if($arr[$i] === 0){
        $zero += 1;
    }
    if($arr[$i] < 0){
        $negative += 1;
    }
}
$fractionPositive = number_format($positive/$countArr, 6);
$fractionNegative = number_format($negative/$countArr, 6);
$fractionZero = number_format($zero/$countArr, 6);

printf("%f\n%f\n%f",$fractionPositive, $fractionNegative, $fractionZero);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I made the code even simpler with Math.sign(), check this out

```
// Complete the plusMinus function below.
function plusMinus(arr) {
    let neg= arr.filter(elem => Math.sign(elem)=== -1).length/arr.length;
    let pos= arr.filter(elem => Math.sign(elem)=== 1).length/arr.length;
    let zer = arr.filter(elem => Math.sign(elem)=== 0).length/arr.length;

    return console.log(pos+ '\n' + neg+ '\n' + zer)

}
```

Math.sign() return 1 for positive number and -1 for negative numbers and 0 for zero,

so here I used array.filter() method to filter those elements which are positive negative and zero respectively and obviously filter() returns a new array, so I took the length of the returned array and divided it with the length of the input array and directly stored it in the variable. That's it. Kudos

Answer (score 0):

I am not a big fan of if-else condition so I have used a **[switch case](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)** here.

```js
function plusMinus(arr) {
    
    let totalPos=0, totalNe=0, totalZe=0, arrLen = arr.length;
    
    for(let value of arr){
        
        switch(true){
           
           case (value > 0):
            totalPos++;
            break;
            
            case (value < 0):
            totalNe++;
            break;             
            
            case (value == 0):
            totalZe++;
            break;           
        }
        
    }
    
    console.log(`${(totalPos/arrLen).toFixed(6)} \n ${(totalNe/arrLen).toFixed(6)} \n ${(totalZe/arrLen).toFixed(6)}`);

}

plusMinus([-4,3,-9,0,4,1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me.

```
def plusMinus(arr):   
    length = len(arr)
    positiveCount = 0
    negativeCount = 0
    zeroCount = 0
    for i in range(length):
        if (arr[i] > 0):
            positiveCount += 1;
        elif(arr[i] < 0):
            negativeCount += 1;
        elif(arr[i] == 0):
            zeroCount += 1;
            
    print("{0:.4f}".format(positiveCount / length));
    print("%1.4f "%(negativeCount / length));
    print("%1.4f "%(zeroCount / length));
    print();
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input().strip())

    arr = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))

    plusMinus(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python Version

```
def plusMinus(arr):
    # Write your code here
    positive_integer = len(list(filter(lambda x: x> 0, arr)))
    negative_integer = len(list(filter(lambda x: x < 0, arr)))
    zero_integer = len(list(filter(lambda x: x == 0, arr)))
    print(positive_integer/len(arr))
    print(negative_integer/len(arr))
    print(zero_integer/len(arr))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code, your logic not have any problem. The problem is:
First, your variable declaration is outside the function.
Second, your return is inside the for - loop.
Third, Instead using return, I prefer use console.log() like this:

```
console.log(FractionOfPostive);
console.log(FractionOfNegative);
console.log(FractionOfZero);
```

I hope this work and helping you.

Answer (score 0):

**I did it in this way which is easy to understand for beginner developers too**

```
  // Write your code here
let posetiveCount = 0;
let negativeCount = 0;
let zeroCount = 0;
arr.forEach((num) => {
    // Count Posetive Numbers
    if(num > 0)  ++posetiveCount;

    // Count Negative count
    if(num < 0) ++negativeCount;

    // Count Zero 
    if(num == 0) ++zeroCount;
}); 

// Calculationg Posetive Ration with 6 desimal
let posetiveNumRatio =  posetiveCount / arr.length;
let negativeNumRatio = negativeCount / arr.length;
let zeroNumRatio = zeroCount / arr.length;

// Console The Result
return console.log(posetiveNumRatio.toFixed(6) + '\n' + negativeNumRatio.toFixed(6) + '\n' + zeroNumRatio.toFixed(6))
```

}

Answer (score -1):

this what Idid

```
function plusMinus(arr) {
    let positive = 0;
    let negative = 0;
    let zero = 0;
    const length = arr.length;

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if (arr[i] > 0) {
            positive +=1
        } else if (arr[i] < 0) {
            negative += 1
        } else {
            zero += 1
       }
     }
function log(a, b, c) {
    console.log(a);
    console.log(b);
    console.log(c);
}

const positiveRatio = (positive / length).toFixed(6);
const negativeRatio = (negative / length).toFixed(6);
const zeroRatio = (zero / length).toFixed(6);

return log(positiveRatio, negativeRatio, zeroRatio)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This solution works. i had to create an additional function to handle the rounding off

```
function plusMinus(arr) {
    let length = arr.length
    let positive = 0
    let negative = 0
    let zero = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++){
        if (arr[i] > 0) {
            positive++
        }
        else if (arr[i] < 0) {
            negative++
        }
        else if (arr[i] == 0) {
            zero++
        }
    }

    const ratioPositive = round((positive / length))
    const ratioNegative = round((negative / length))
    const ratioZero = round((zero / length))

    console.log( ratioPositive + "\n" + ratioNegative + "\n" + ratioZero )

}

function round(value) {
    return Number(value).toFixed(6);
  }

plusMinus([-4, 3, -9, 0, 4, 1])
```

Output:

```
0.500000
0.333333
0.166667
```

Answer (score -1):

The following function works:

```
function plusMinus(arr) {
    let zero = parseFloat(arr.filter(val = > val == 0).length / arr.length).toPrecision(6)
    let pos = parseFloat(arr.filter(val = > val > 0).length / arr.length).toPrecision(6)
    let neg = parseFloat(arr.filter(val = > val < 0).length / arr.length).toPrecision(6)
    console.log(pos)
    console.log(neg)
    console.log(zero)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here result is for [positive, negative, zero] counts, in forEach loop corresponding value is incrementing.

```
function plusMinus(arr) {
  const result = [0, 0, 0]
  arr.forEach(item =>
    result[item > 0 ? 0 : item ? 1 : 2]++
  )
  console.log(result.map(item => (item / arr.length).toFixed(6)).join('\n'))
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem, or how this differs from the existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/25006359)

Answer (score -1):

```js
var arr = [-4, 3, -9, 0, 4, 1];



function plusMinus(arr) {
  var n = arr.length;
  var positive = 0,
    negative = 0,
    zero = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (arr[i] > 0) {
      positive += 1;
    } else if (arr[i] < 0) {
      negative += 1;
    } else {
      zero += 1;
    }
  }

  var pos = positive / n;
  var neg = negative / n;
  var zer = zero / n;
  console.log(pos.toFixed(6) + "\n" + neg.toFixed(6) + "\n" + zer.toFixed(6));
}

plusMinus(arr);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple solution that involves using a `for-of` loop, `array destructuring`, and `template literals`.

```js
function plusMinus(arr) {

    let count = [0, 0, 0];

    let [count1, count2, count3] = count;  

    let length = arr.length;
        
    for (let val of arr) {      
    
      if (val > 0) { 

          count1++

      } 
      else if (val < 0) { 

          count2++ 
      } 
      else {

          count3++

      }

    }

 console.log(`${(count1/length).toFixed(6)}\n ${(count2/length).toFixed(6)}\n ${(count3/length).toFixed(6)}`);         
}

plusMinus([-4,3,-9,0,4,1]);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const plusMinus = function (num, arr) {
let positives = 0, negatives = 0, zeros = 0;
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] > 0) {
        positives ++
    } else if (arr[i] < 0) {
        negatives ++
    } else if(arr[i] === 0) {
        zeros ++
    }
}
 console.log((positives / arr.length).toFixed(6));
 console.log((negatives / arr.length).toFixed(6));
 console.log((zeros / arr.length).toFixed(6));
};

plusMinus(6, [-4, 3, -9, 0, 4, 1]);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function plusMinus(arr) {
    let no_positive = 0
    let no_negative = 0
    let no_zero = 0
    
    for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] < 0) {
            no_negative++
        } 
        
        if (arr[i]>0) {
            no_positive++
        } 

        if (arr[i]==0) {
            no_zero++
        }
    }
    var posRatio = (no_positive/arr.length).toFixed(6);
    var negRatio = (no_negative/arr.length).toFixed(6);
    var zeroRatio = (no_zero/arr.length).toFixed(6);
    console.log(posRatio)
    console.log(negRatio)
    console.log(zeroRatio)
}
```

Comment: How is this better than, or improve on, the other answers?

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive-feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).

Answer (score -1):

There is an issue in your for loop. You need to write your if statement via checking the array values subject to your index variable in the loop. You can compare your solution with the one below.

```
function plusMinus(arr) {
  let plus = 0;
  let minus = 0;
  let zero = 0;
  const arrLen = arr.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] > 0) {
        plus++;
    } else if (arr[i] < 0) {
        minus++;
    }
    else {
        zero++;
    }
  }

  return console.log(
    (plus / arrLen).toFixed(6) +
    "\n" +
    (minus / arrLen).toFixed(6) +
    "\n" +
    (zero / arrLen).toFixed(6) + 
    "\n"
  );

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function plusMinus(arr) {
    let n=arr.length;
    let poscount=0
    let negcount=0
    let zerocounnt=0
    for(let i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(arr[i]>0){
            poscount+=1
        }else if(arr[i]<0){
            negcount+=1
        }else{
            zerocounnt+=1
        }       
    }
    console.log((poscount/n).toFixed(6))
    console.log((negcount/n).toFixed(6))
    console.log((zerocounnt/n).toFixed(6))
}
plusMinus([-4 3 -9 0 4 1])
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please provide a summary of how your answer solves the problem and why it may be preferable to the other answers already provided.

Answer (score -1):

To refactor your code you need to return statement as below:

```
function plusMinus(arr) {
// Your code here
   return result(countPositive, countNegative, countZero);
}

function result(pos, neg, zero) {
    console.log(pos);
    console.log(neg);
    console.log(zero);
}
```

Another way of writing code is as below :

```
function plusMinus(arr) {
// Write your code here
let arrLen = arr.length;
let countPositive = (arr.filter(num => num>0).length/arrLen).toFixed(6);
let countNegative = (arr.filter(num => num<0).length/arrLen).toFixed(6);
let countZero = (arr.filter(num => num===0).length/arrLen).toFixed(6);
return result(countPositive, countNegative, countZero);
}

function result(pos, neg, zero) {
    console.log(pos);
    console.log(neg);
    console.log(zero);
}
```